# Excel- Referencing a cell containing a name that refers to a dynamic range

Tags: excel

I'm using name manager, but my reference in name manager is dynamic because im working with live data and needs to change its range accordingly, like:
name: Dynamo refers to:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$I$12,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$I$12:$I$1005),1)
```

and I have a cell (I10) on the sheet whose value is "Dynamo"
I want a Sum of "Dynamo" by referring to I10 instead of `=SUM(Test)`

I've tried `SUM(INDIRECT(I10))`, which works if the range is static, but not dynamic
if your range for "Dynamo" is "$A$1:$A$10", its static
but if your range is:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$I$12,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$I$12:$I$1005),1)
```

It's dynamic and indirect doesn't work.

I would like to essentially refer to a cell that contains a name which points to an array.

Comment: How can i upload a sample excel sheet i've created here?

Comment: As Offset returns a range, there is no need for indirect. Also one cell only can be one cell... either make I10 returning the range of dynamo as a string, then `=SUM(INDIRECT(I10))` will work or go for `=SUM(Dynamo)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to sum Sheet1!I:I from row 12 to the last row with numerical values.

```
=sum(Sheet1!$I$12:index(Sheet1!$I:$I, match(1e99, Sheet1!$I:$I)))
```